# How to change permission on a file in unix?

Tags: unix

im running the oracle vm box but truing the chmod 7000 on a file ,But it;s not working.Permissions a re not applying.
Need help?

Comment: Would you mind telling us what you are actually trying to archieve instead of writing what didn't work?

Comment: Trying my best to find a solution

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
chmod 700 file.txt
```

7 - user rwx

0 - group none

0 - others none

Answer (score 1):

`chmod 7000 file` should be setting `setuid` `setgid` and the sticky bit. (Equivalent to `chmod ug+s,+t file`). Are you sure you don't mean `chmod 0700`? This can help: http://permissions-calculator.org/symbolic/